# CSS Not Loading Correctly

Tags: css

The following CSS is causing headaches for me.  It works on the local server (IE) but not in any other browser. After adding this, none of my CSS works.

```
txtBlock {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  background: #2d2f33;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: -20em;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 0;
  width: 20em;
  z-index: 2000;
  transition: right 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: right 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: right 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
  opacity: .92;
   text-shadow:-9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  -moz-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  -o-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  -ms-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 

  }
```

If I flip it like this:

```css
text-shadow:-9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-moz-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-o-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-ms-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

It doesn't work in any browser.  I am assuming this is the issue, because it worked prior to adding the code.

My question is could the offending piece of CSS cause all of my CSS to crash?  I was just wondering if something may have stood out to someone.  Thank you for the replies, any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any question here. (Also: Please don't use stack snippets (`<>`) for things that aren't runnable, use the `{}` button instead.)

Comment: you added this inside a css selector, yes?

Comment: Show us yourrelevant CSS code including selectors

Comment: `txtBlock` missing a dot or hash or is that a copy and paste error? Also `right:-20em`, means it is off the page and you won't see it

Comment: Pete.  I just changed the name to paste.  The CSS worked prior to adding the text-shadow part.  I don't think I changed anything else, but it seems as though the browsers aren't reading any of my CSS after adding the lines regarding text shadow.  It seems like it is blowing up there (if that's possible)

Comment: Pete, that is by design.  It is a navigation menu that is hidden off of screen.

Comment: I think it may be the -9px (or any of the four values) that is messing it up - if you remove that it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8vo34c6n/, most examples I've seen only use up to 3 values before the colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the 4 pixel values before your colour - there should only be three:

- the first value = The X-coordinate
- the second value = The Y-coordinate
- the third value = The blur radius
- the fourth value = The colour of the shadow

If you change your css to have only 3 values before the colour it should work:

```
text-shadow:-9px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-moz-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-o-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-ms-text-shadow: -9px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8vo34c6n/1/)

[More info about text-shadow](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-text-shadow/)

Comment: I would agree that your jfiddle works, but it doesn't seem to solve my current problem (after making the changes you suggest, my CSS still doesn't load).  Should I mark your answer as correct, even though I can't verify it on my project?

Comment: what happens in your project when you correct the errors?  When you say it doesn't work, what happens - no css at all or just no css for that element?

Comment: Everything is white, like no CSS is applied, even in IE where it previously would work.

Comment: If you inspect the element, does it show any errors / styles crossed out?

Comment: no, I don't see errors and I don't see any styles crossed out, but I don't see any of my styles on the entire page.

Comment: Then without seeing the code, there's not really a lot else I can suggest - if you use the fixed code and it is still breaking, then it would lead me to believe that it is something else that is causing the page to break

Comment: OK. thank you for your help.  I'll keep seeing if I messed up something elsewhere.